# Calculate duration of two points in time ISO 8601

Tags: java, time, duration, iso8601

I'm having the following data:

```
"startAt": "PT0S",
"endAt": "PT21M12.667S"
```

startAt defines the start of a video and endAt the end of the video.
How can I calculate the time between these points? I guess its ISO 8601 and I am using Java, but the library I tried (Joda) doens't work with the endAt paramter.

Comment: Convert them to timestamps and subtract? (timestamp like in "milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00 UTC")

Comment: @Fildor And to convert them to milliseconds? That's probably the problem

Comment: @Cruncher I guess so. Haven't looked at that ISO, yet...

Comment: @Cruncher Jon was faster ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are ISO-8601 *period* values (not points in time) - and Joda Time handles them fine:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startText = "PT0S";
        String endText = "PT21M12.667S";

        PeriodFormatter format = ISOPeriodFormat.standard();
        Period start = format.parsePeriod(startText);
        Period end = format.parsePeriod(endText);

        Duration duration = end.minus(start).toStandardDuration();
        System.out.println(duration); // PT1272.667S
        System.out.println(duration.getMillis()); // 1272667
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know everything? Or are you just a research god?

Comment: @Cruncher: Well date and time APIs are very close to my heart, so it didn't take long to whip up the sample code...

Comment: Thank you very much Sir! I just didn't understand the point char between the 12 and the 667 but this works fine! Keep up the great work :)

Answer (score 0):

### Using Java-8 standard library

[`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) is modelled on [ISO-8601 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and was introduced as part of [JSR-310 implementation](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/pfd/jsr310/JSR-310-guide.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Duration;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String startAt = "PT0S";
        String endAt = "PT21M12.667S";
        Duration start = Duration.parse(startAt);
        Duration end = Duration.parse(endAt);
        long millis = end.minus(start).toMillis();
        System.out.println(millis);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1272667
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

- For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7.
- If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).